# Service Availability issue

Tags: java, apache, web-services, jboss

We are facing two general issues in our production env and would like to get recommendations.

We are using cluster of nodes running Jboss and apache web server for load balancing.

The two problems are,

1. All the server nodes work fine normally, however, suddenly within a minute, one of the node reach out the maximum DB connection limit (say, from 30 to 100) and start throwing errors (Unable to get manage connection).
2. I have seen that sometimes, we got simultaneously lot of same webservice calls from one user. For instance, more than 1000 web service calls of the same service by same user within a minute. It looks like, may be user is stuck in some kind of repetitive loop in browser (not sure).

To fix first problem, I have seen we don't have any connection leak issue. Mostly, we found that the service response time becomes very high, however the load balancer sends the equal traffic to each node and therefore possibly, this node might get exhausted. One solution I was thinking is to timeout the service call  earlier which takes more than certain time but I am not sure is it good idea. Any thoughts, what recommendations/practice available to tackle such situation?

To fix second problem, I think the application should not defend or check for such large number of service calls but it should be in the higher level like firewall or web server. However, I would like to know your thoughts for this.

I hope my question make sense but if it doesn't, please feel free to ask,